# Размытие изображения в панели многозадачности iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, blur

Для скрытия информации требуется «заблюрить» экран приложения, когда он отображается в панели многозадачность.

Подобное встречается во многих банковских приложениях, или, например, реализуется некоторыми «твиками».

Как реализовать подобную «фичу»?

Пример *PayPal* приложения:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher

Размытие изображения в панели многозадачность:

В `applicationWillResignActive`

Swift:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = window!.frame
blurEffectView.tag = 221122 //любой тег

self.window?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Objective-C:

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
blurEffectView.frame = self.window.frame;
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[self.window addSubview:blurEffectView];
```

Для отключения размытия добавить

Swift: `self.window?.viewWithTag(221122)?.removeFromSuperview()`
Obj-c: `[[self.window viewWithTag:221122] removeFromSuperview]` в `applicationWillEnterForeground` и `applicationDidBecomeActive`